# Possessive Apostrophe

Tags: possessives, apostrophe

Rorys approach was different, taking a leaf out of one of his favourite games. The game’s most memorable lesson for Rory was blackmail.

Is the apostrophe in this case correct?

Comment: The apostrophe in **game's** is correct, but you should have one in **Rory's** at the start of your question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is a genitive.  Whose most memorable lesson? The game's.

Whose can be considered to work with things, too.

Thanks to @MichaelHarvey:
Also at the beginning,  there should be an apostrophe.  Whose approach? Rory's.